# Is there a Rolling implementation of PCA in python?

Tags: numpy, time-series, pca, numba, rolling-computation

For time-series analysis, it's useful to have rolling PCA functions to analyse how the dynamics of the time-series changes over time to **[avoid look-ahead bias](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lookaheadbias.asp)**.

We may want to answer the question: 'how many principle components are needed to keep 90% of the variance?'. The number of principle components to explain 90% variance may change over time, depending on the dynamics of the time-series.

In addition, we may want to reduce the number of components p in a given dataset to k < p on a rolling basis to more easily visualise the data.

While scikit has a [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) module, it does not support rolling calculations. Similarly with [numpy SVD](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html). We could use these packages in a manual for loop, but for large arrays (>10,000 rows) it would become very slow.

Is there a **fast rolling** implementation of PCA in python to address some of the questions above?

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't manage to find a rolling implementation of PCA, it is a relatively straightforward matter to use the packages and tools mentioned in the question to code a manual rolling PCA function. In addition, we will use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html) to gain a small speed-up, as it supports [numpy.linalg.svd](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) and [numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

The code in this answer is inspired by the excellent explanations of PCA [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
from numba import njit
import numpy.typing as npt


@njit
def rolling_pca(
        arr: npt.NDArray[np.float64],
        n_components: int,
        window: int,
        min_periods: int
) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
    """Perform PCA on the covariance matrix of arr.

    Return the lower dimensional array.

    Data is assumed to have non-zero mean, so will be demeaned
    in the process.

    Args:
        arr: Input data. Shape (n_samples, n_variables).
        n_components: Number of components to reduce data matrix to.
            Must be less than arr.shape[1].
        window: Sliding window size.
        min_periods: Minimum number of observations required to perform calculation.

    Returns:
        Reduced data matrix. Shape (n_samples, n_components)
    """
    # create a copy to ensure we don't change data in place
    arr_copy = arr.copy()
    n = arr_copy.shape[0]
    # create an empty array which will be populated with the output
    reduced_out = np.full((n, n_components), np.nan)
    # iterate over each row (timestamp in a timeseries)
    for i in range(min_periods, n + 1):
        if i < window:
            lookback = i
        else:
            lookback = window
        start_idx = i - lookback
        curr_arr = arr_copy[start_idx: i, :]
        # demean returns
        curr_arr = curr_arr - (np.sum(curr_arr, axis=0) / lookback)
        # calculate the covariance matrix
        cov = (curr_arr.T @ curr_arr) / (lookback - 1)
        # get the eigenvectors
        # sort eigvals to get top largest corresponding eigenvectors
        evals, evecs = eig(cov)
        idx = np.argsort(evals)[:n_components]
        evecs = evecs[:, idx]
        # multiply the top eigenvectors by the current array to get a reduced matrix
        reduced = (evecs.T @ curr_arr.T).T
        reduced_out[start_idx: i, :] = reduced
    return reduced_out
```

After profiling the code, the two slowest parts are, as expected, the calls to `eig()` and the matrix multiplication `curr_arr.T @ curr_arr`. As the array `curr_arr` is limited by the window size, a pure numpy (no numba) implementation of matrix multiplcation is faster than using numba. This is because the arrays used in the matrix multiplication are small, and are not contiguous (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more details). I didn't get around to resolving this issue, but if anyone has any suggestions, it would speed up this function quite a bit more.

I've compared the average timings between 3 implementations to see the effect of the speedup that numba offers. The 3 implementations are:

- Manual for loop using numba, exactly as above
- Manual for loop without numba, but otherwise same as the code above
- Manual for loop using Sklearn instead of numpy `eig`, no numba (as numba does not support Sklearn)

Note that the following parameters are fixed so we get as fair a comparison as possible between implementations

- Window size = 120
- Minimum number of periods = 22
- Input data number of variables = 20
- Number of components to reduce to via PCA = 10
- Number of iterations to time function over so as to get an average timing per implementation = 10

Only the row size (number of samples) is allowed to vary so we can visualise how execution time varies with array length.

[image]

We can see for large arrays (100k rows), we can decrease the time from about 14.19s using Sklearn, to 5.36s using numba, about a 2.6X speedup.

### PCA Reconstruction

We implement some code similar to what we used above to **reconstruct** the original data matrix, using only the top principle components. Namely, we use SVD to decompose the matrix `X` into 3 matrices, `U`, `S`, and `V^T`. With these matrices, we can calculate how much variance is kept cumulatively by the components, and only keep the top `k` components that explain a desired amount of variance.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import svd
from numba import njit
import numpy.typing as npt


@njit
def __get_num_top_components(
        singular_values: npt.NDArray[np.float64],
        threshold: float,
        n: int,
) -> int:
    """Get the number of top eigen-components required by threshold.

    Args:
        singular_values: Singular values from SVD.
        threshold: Minimum amount of explained variance to be kept.
        n: Number of samples in data matrix.

    Returns:
        Required number of components to keep.
    """
    evals = singular_values ** 2 / (n - 1)
    evals = evals / np.sum(evals)
    cumsum_evals = np.cumsum(evals)
    top_k = np.argwhere(cumsum_evals > threshold).min()
    return top_k


@njit
def rolling_pca_reconstruction(
        arr: npt.NDArray[np.float64],
        threshold: float,
        window: int,
        min_periods: int
) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
    """Perform PCA on arr and return reconstructed matrix.

    This method follows the logic succinctly outlined here:
    https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134283/178320

    Args:
        arr: Input data. Shape (n_samples, n_variables).
        threshold: Minimum amount of explained variance to be kept.
            Must be a number in (0., 1.).
        window: Sliding window size.
        min_periods: Minimum number of observations required to perform calculation.

    Returns:
        Reconstructed data matrix. Shape (n_samples, n_variables)
    """
    arr_copy = arr.copy()
    n = arr_copy.shape[0]
    p = arr_copy.shape[1]
    recon_out = np.full((n, p), np.nan)
    for i in range(min_periods, n + 1):
        if i < window:
            lookback = i
        else:
            lookback = window
        start_idx = i - lookback
        curr_arr = arr_copy[start_idx: i, :]
        # demean data
        curr_arr = curr_arr - (np.sum(curr_arr, axis=0) / lookback)
        # perform SVD on data, no need for full matrices, this is faster
        u, s, vh = svd(curr_arr, full_matrices=False)
        # calculate the number of components that explains threshold variance
        top_k = __get_num_top_components(
            singular_values=s,
            threshold=threshold,
            n=lookback,
        )
        # reconstruct the data matrix using the top_k components
        tmp_recon = u[:, :top_k] @ np.diag(s)[:top_k, :top_k] @ vh[:, :top_k].T
        recon_out[start_idx: i, :] = tmp_recon
    return recon_out
```

The output of `rolling_pca_reconstruction()` is the reconstructed data, of same dimension as the input data `arr`. One useful modification that could be made to this code is to record `top_k` at each iteration, to understand how many components are needed to explain `treshold` variance over time.